# How to determine in .NET if a file is UCS-2 vs. UTF-16

Tags: encoding, utf-16, ucs2

I have flat files that I can load just fine in .NET in UTF-16, even though they are technically UCS2-LE (w/o BOM), and I understand this is because UCS-2 is an older standard that UTF-16 supercedes.

However, what I'm interested in is being able to determine if a file actually is UCS-2. I know that this means I'd be guessing. I have tried the .NET ports of chardet, the IMultilang2 interop, and some open source by Novell for trying to tease out a determination of UCS-2 over UTF-16 and I haven't had any success. I haven't found any technique that can determine the difference between UCS-2LE w/o BOM and invalid/overlong UTF-8.

Should I be inspecting them byte for byte and trying to decide if it's variable or fixed length encoding? Maybe look for missing codepoints? The issue is these text files have no special codepoints, they only have the bog standard Western character set. But TextPad saves them as UCS2-LE w/o BOM, and it complicates downstream file operations in our software that wants them to be fully compliant UTF-16 (and just force loading the files works, but won't work with the software's requirements).

Comment: This might help: [https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/bazaar/2007q2/025942.html](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/bazaar/2007q2/025942.html) Quote: *When interpreting what people have meant by "UCS-2" in past usage, it is
best thought of as not a data format, but as an indication that an
implementation does not interpret any supplementary characters. In
particular, for the purposes of data exchange, UCS-2 and UTF-16 are
identical formats. Both are 16-bit, and have exactly the same code unit
representation.*

Comment: That's the problem; I can use existing heuristics to detect UTF-16, but those implementations can't figure out UCS-2LE w/o BOM files. I want to treat them the same, but I end up having to use a fallback encoding because I can't find a way to determine the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This wikipedia article section, [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B0000_to_U.2BD7FF_and_U.2BE000_to_U.2BFFFF),
speaks about the Basic Multilingual Plane, BMP. All code points in the BMP is identical for both UTF-16 and UCS-2. If TextPad is just encoding the BMP then you can treat the document as either UTF-16 or UCS-2.

It is when code points outside the BMP are encoded that a problem arises. **UCS-2 cannot represent code points outside the BMP.** [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set#Encoding_forms_of_the_Universal_Character_Set)
This would lead one to assume that if a code point is outside the BMP then it can be treated at UTF-16. This could be problematic if the program creating the file was doing UCS-2 improperly and using codepoints outside the BMP for ancillary reasons.

Most libraries and programs that read UTF allow you to specify what to do when an encoding error occurs on a per character basis(raise an exception, replace with a placeholder, simply ignore). If an improper UCS-2 file is run through one of these as UTF-16 it will raise errors. Understanding what the author of the file was trying to do outside the BMP would be the only way to handle them appropriately.

Comment: That is all absolutely correct, but I cannot get tools like the .NET port of chardet, IMultiLang2, etc. to guess UTF-16 for any UCS-2LE file when there is no BOM. It's correct that TextPad is just storing the BMP, but I can't get my software to figure that out in a bullet proof way. However, this is basically the answer, in those situations I can run through the file and determine if the code points are in the BMP. The part I don't like is how I can't find a heuristic that can guess this on its own when there is no BOM.